# SFMC Journey Builder Custom Activity outArguments usage issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, custom, custom-activity

I have a SFMC custom REST activity that fetches data from our internal API and assigns the data to out arguments of my custom REST activity.

I can use a decision split on the out arguments of my custom rest activity however I cannot use the out arguments within another custom rest api body or with a update contact activity. I have tried to use the out arguments within another custom rest api execute body by specifying the format {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} like I do with all my journey attributes, however the journey cannot even activate if I specify {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}}. If I remove the {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} then my journey can activate but I require the out argument value.

Does anyone know how I can use REST out arguments within another custom REST activity or within an update contact activity?

Comment: I installed the Postman like journey builder activity from https://www.sfmc-postman.com/. Its a really powerful and essential tool to have. I have been able to make custom API request in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey builder. 
It works exactly the same as postman.
I can also create templates, environment variables and use response variables in my journey. Their analytics is also great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data-binding is the mechanism to consume an `outArgument` from a previous activity.

**For Custom Activity**

To consume `outArguments`, the syntax would be `{{Interaction.activityKey.outArgumentField}}`

The `activityKey` can be found manually.

> For the manual process, you can get it manually by inspecting the element in devtools of the Journey Data on the settings page in Journey Builder.

[image]

> For Programmatically you can find by using a `postmonger` signal called `requestInteraction` which returns information about the journey itself.  This will include every activity on the canvas.

There is a repo here (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-example-jb-custom-activity/blob/master/modules/discount-code/config/config-json.js) that shows both the examples of how to build config files and split and pass arguments.

There is an example of this [here](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-example-jb-custom-activity/blob/master/modules/discount-redemption-split/src/index.js#L71)

In this example, it actually loads a drop-down list to the user of all activities that have `discountCode` as an `outArgument`.  The selected value of that drop down is the `activitykey` that it got from the `postmonger` signal.So basically it iterates over each activity and inspects the schema specified to find potential `outArguments` to use from previous activities

**For Update Contact Activity**

The Update Contact activity does not support selecting from Journey Data natively, but it is possible to manually type in the mustache data binding expression and get the desired result when the contact executes through the activity.

More on data-binding: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm

The hard part is knowing the `activityKey/outargument` field name of previous activities.  This can be achieved using some `postmonger` signals in a custom activity to get metadata about the journey itself

Comment: Hi @Mohith Shrivastava I got the update contact activity working with using {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} as the value. 

However when I use another custom activity in the journey and reference OutArguments from my previous custom activity I cannot even activate my journey when I use the value {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} from the previous custom activity. I can however use journey DE values such as Event.DEAudience-58942cb2-9aec-071a-fc07-eef3660ce9ad.SubscriberKey within my second custom activity. 

Any idea why and if this is possible?

Comment: Is REST-1 your activity key? Make sure to find your correct activity key? If it is still throwing error open a support case with Salesforce

Comment: Hi @Mohith Shrivastava, yes REST-1 is my activity key I am 100% sure of it. My contact update activity also works 100% with {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} however if I use {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} within another custom activity the journey cannot activate and throws an error but no error message. Will support be able to provide information on the backend error why I cannot activate my journey?

Comment: Yes for sure! Raise a support ticket with all the repro steps and I am sure someone will be able to assist you

Comment: I installed the Postman like journey builder activity from https://www.sfmc-postman.com/. Its a really powerful and essential tool to have. I have been able to make custom API request in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey builder. 
It works exactly the same as postman.
I can also create templates, environment variables and use response variables in my journey. Their analytics is also great.